# Show martingality property for r.v. $S_{\infty}$, given some assumptions. Could you please detail your answer to my two points?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, conditional-expectation, martingales

Given a probability space $(\Omega$, $\mathcal{F}$, $\mathbb{P})$, let $(S_n)_{n\geq1}$ be a martingale and a sequence of uniformly integrable random variables. Also assume $S_n\rightarrow S_{\infty}$ in $\mathcal{L}^1$, that is $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\{|S_n-S_{\infty}|\}=0$. Finally, $S_{\infty}$ is in $\mathcal{L}^1$.

**I would like to show $\mathbb{E}\{S_{\infty}\mid\mathcal{F}_n\}=S_n$.**

First of all, let $n\geq m$ and $\Lambda\in\mathcal{F}_m$. Then, by martingale property:
$$
\mathbb{E}\{S_n1_{\Lambda}\}=\mathbb{E}\{S_m1_{\Lambda}\}
$$

At this point, from JACOD-PROTTER I read:

> However,
>   \begin{align*}
> |\mathbb{E}\{S_n1_{\Lambda}\}-\mathbb{E}\{S_{\infty}1_{\Lambda}\}| &\leq \mathbb{E}\{|S_n-S_{\infty}|1_{\Lambda}\}\\&\leq\mathbb{E}\{|S_n-S_{\infty}|\}
> \end{align*}
>   which tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$.

**A SHORT COMMENT OF MINE**: *Notice that first inequality follows from Jensen's inequality (since both $M_n$ and $M_{\infty}$ are integrable, i.e. in $\mathcal{L}^1$, and absolute value is a convex function), while the fact that $\mathbb{E}\{|S_n-S_{\infty}|\}$ "tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$" follows from $S_n\rightarrow S_{\infty}$ in $\mathcal{L}^1$, i.e. $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\{|S_n-S_{\infty}|\}=0$.*

> $\color{red}{Thus}$ $\mathbb{E}\{S_m1_{\Lambda}\}=\mathbb{E}\{S_{\infty}1_{\Lambda}\}$ and $\color{red}{hence}$ $\mathbb{E}\{S_{\infty}\mid\mathcal{F}_n\}=S_n$ a.s.

I cannot understand the two logical implications in red.
1) "$\color{red}{thus}$" part: as far as I understood, in the first quoted block one gets to the fact that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\mathbb{E}\{S_n1_{\Lambda}\}-\mathbb{E}\{S_{\infty}1_{\Lambda}\}|=0$. So, the **first question** is: why does $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\mathbb{E}\{S_n1_{\Lambda}\}-\mathbb{E}\{S_{\infty}1_{\Lambda}\}|=0$ imply that $\mathbb{E}\{S_m1_{\Lambda}\}=\mathbb{E}\{S_{\infty}1_{\Lambda}\}$?
2) "$\color{red}{hence}$" part (**second question**): why does $\mathbb{E}\{S_m1_{\Lambda}\}=\mathbb{E}\{S_{\infty}1_{\Lambda}\}$ imply that $\mathbb{E}\{S_{\infty}\mid\mathcal{F}_n\}=S_n$ a.s.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\F{\mathscr{F}}\def\G{\mathscr{G}}\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$1) Note that$$
\lim_{n → ∞} |E(S_n I_A) - E(S_∞ I_A)| = 0 \Longrightarrow \lim_{n → ∞} E(S_n I_A) = E(S_∞ I_A).
$$
Since it is already shown by the martingale property that$$
E(S_m I_A) = E(S_n I_A), \quad \forall n \geqslant m
$$
then$$
E(S_m I_A) = \lim_{n → ∞} E(S_n I_A) = E(S_∞ I_A).
$$

2) To rephrase what has been proved up to the “hence”:

> For any $n \geqslant 1$, if $A \in \F_n$ then $E(S_n I_A) = E(S_∞ I_A)$. $\qquad(*)$

Now recall the definition of conditional expectations:

> For an integrable random variable $X$ on a probability space $({\mit Ω}, P, \F)$ and a sub-σ-algebra $\G \subseteq \F$, a random variable $Y$ in this space is said to be the *conditional expectation of $X$ given $\G$* if:
>
> 1. $Y$ is $\G$-measurable, and
>
>    $\displaystyle\int_A X\,\d P = \int_A Y \,\d P$ for any $A \in \G$.

So ($*$) proves by the definition that $E(S_∞ \mid \F_n) = S_n$ since $S_n$ is $\F_n$-measurable.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, in my specific case, referring to the notation of the definition you have provided, $\mathcal{F}_n$ corresponds to the $G$ of the definition, $E(S_{\infty}\vert \mathcal{F}_n)$ corresponds to the $Y$ of the definition and finally $S_{\infty}$ corresponds to the $X$ of the definition. **[CONTINUE]**

Comment: **[CONTINUE]** @Saad: At this point (first equation below by $I_A\in \mathcal{F}_n$, second equation below by def. of conditional expect. (considering that $S_n\in\mathcal{F}_n$), third equation below by $E(S_{\infty}I_{A})=E(S_{n}I_{A})$): $$E(I_{A}E(S_{\infty}\vert\mathcal{F}_n))=E(E(I_{A}S_{\infty}\vert\mathcal{F}_n))=E(S_{\infty}I_{A})=E(S_{n}I_{A})$$
Hence, $S_n$ ($\in\mathcal{F}_n$) is by definition the conditional expectation of $S_{\infty}$ given $\mathcal{F}_n$, that is $S_n=E(S_{\infty}|\mathcal{F}_n)$. *ARE ALL MY PASSAGES CORRECT?*

Comment: @Strictly_increasing Your deduction is correct but makes the unnecessary detour by assuming the existence of $E(S_∞\mid\mathscr F_n)$ first (since it's written out on the LHS of your identity.)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your exhaustive anc completely "doubt-clearing" answer. Just one last thing, could you please give me a good reference as to the definition of conditional expectation you have provided above? Thank you!!! @Saad